# Limit of a Lebesgue integral over a sum?

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration

I am trying to evaluate the following integral:

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{(0,1)} \sum^{2n+1}_{k=0} (-1)^{k} x^{2k} dm(x)$

Attempt:

Let $f_{n}(x)=\sum^{2n+1}_{k=0} (-1)^{k} x^{2k}$

Then $f_{n}(x)$ can be written as:

$f_{n}(x)=1-x^{2}+x^{4}-...+x^{4n}-x^{4n+2}$
$=(1-x^{2})(1+x^{4}+...+x^{4n})$

Now for all $x \in (0,1)$, $(1-x^{2})>0$ and $(1+x^{4}+...+x^{4n})>1$

So $f_{n}(x)$ is a sequence of non negative functions that are increasing as $f_{n+1}(x) =f_{n}(x)+(1-x^{2})x^{4n+4}>f_{n}(x)$

Then we can use the monotone convergence theorem:

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{(0,1)} \sum^{2n+1}_{k=0} (-1)^{k} x^{2k} dm(x)$
$ = \int_{(0,1)} \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum^{2n+1}_{k=0} (-1)^{k} x^{2k} dm(x)$
$ =  \int_{(0,1)} \sum^{\infty}_{k=0} (-1)^{k} x^{2k} dm(x)$

The function is bounded and continuous over (0,1), so the Lebesgue and Riemann integrals coincide. In which case we have:

$ \int_{(0,1)} \sum^{\infty}_{k=0} (-1)^{k} x^{2k} dm(x) =  \int_{0}^{1} \sum^{\infty}_{k=0} (-1)^{k} x^{2k} dx$

Now I'm not sure if what I've done up to this point is correct, and I'm not sure how to proceed from here. Integrating the above expression gets me $\sum^{\infty}_{k=0} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{2k+1}$ which I'm not sure how to evaluate. But the following question says to use the result from this question to evaluate the sum $\sum^{\infty}_{k=0} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{2k+1}$ which makes me think that there is an alternative way to calculate the integral that will allow me to evaluate the sum?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hint : Lebesgue integration is linear hence $\int_{(0,1)} \sum_{k=0}^{2n+1} (-1)^k x^{2k} dm(x) =  \sum_{k=0}^{2n+1}(-1)^k \int_{(0,1)}  x^{2k} dm(x)$. You reasoning can be applied to solve the following question that you mention.

Comment: @P.Quinton Doesn't that result in the same sum?

Comment: Well yes but you can evaluate the second to be $\sum_{k=0}^{2n+1} \frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1} $ and proceed.

Comment: @P.Quinton maybe I'm missing something, but I'm not sure how that helps me? How do I evaluate \sum_{k=0}^{2n+1} (-1)^{k}/(2k+1)?

Answer (score 2):

For $x\lt 1$, $\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^kx^{2k}=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$.  Then $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x^2}dm(x)=\frac{\pi}{4}$  To be rigorous, you need to show $\int_{1-u}^1\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^kx^{2k}dm(x)\to 0$, as $u\to 0$.

Comment: Thank you. I understand that, but I don't understand the second part you put about showing the integral goes to zero as u goes to zero. Is this because it's an open interval so 1 isn't included?

Comment: Essentially yes, but the proof of the last part is trivial, since $\sum_{k=0}^N(-1)^kx^{2k}$ is bounded as $N\to \infty$, even though it does not converge.